# Why the RPS in locust doesn't change at distributed state?

Tags: locust

I have met a problem when I want to run load tests on a server using locust.

I set the users number = 4000, the min_wait = 5000 and the max_wait = 15000.

I think the RPS(requests per second) should be around 400, but it's around 100.

Then I try to run it with 3 slaves at different device, which should increase the value of RPS, but it doesn't work and still be around 100.

What's wrong with my configuration or my understanding?

Comment: Are you sure your server can handle more than 100 RPS? It sounds like your server cannot handle more than that. On average it looks like you are running a request every 10 seconds and with 4000 users you should be seeing much higher even not in distributed mode.

Comment: Are you able to increase/decrease the RPS with the increase/decrease in user numbers?

Comment: Any update on this question?